# Two people can't have the same technology ? It looks the same to me from what I can see

Tags: us8276545

This patent looks like it does the same think as my patent #12/674,848
I would like to know more about the other patent.

Comment: These are the related patents: http://www.google.com/patents/us8276545 http://www.google.com/patents/US8210129

Comment: Welcome to ask patents -- this place is not about discussing disputes in patent other than calling for prior art references -- please check out http://patents.stackexchange.com/help to see how to best ask a question